# Does MigraDoc support national characters/ unicode characters?

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, migradoc

I’m using MigraDoc for generating PDF documents. It works very well but I have 2 problems:

1. I cannot add Polish characters (especially ł) to text like.
2. I cannot add pound character (₤) to text.

I tried to change font, but no result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved this on my own:)

Using Unicode fonts can be set in 2 ways:

1) by PdfDocumentRenderer  constructor:

```
PdfDocumentRenderer pdfRenderer = new PdfDocumentRenderer(true, PdfFontEmbedding.Always);
```

2) by options;

```
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

    XPdfFontOptions options = new XPdfFontOptions(PdfFontEncoding.Unicode, PdfFontEmbedding.Always);
```

Additional example here:
http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/Unicode-sample.ashx

Comment: can this be done entirely in MigraDoc or do I need to convert everything to  PDFSharp? I'm trying to use the character \u260E and I'm having a bit of trouble with it.

Comment: The first solution doesn't work for me.
It seems MigraDoc document doesn't play nicely with PdfSharp's document renderer.
Whole story: [net-c-sharp-migradoc-how-to-change-document-charset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822852/net-c-sharp-migradoc-how-to-change-document-charset)

Comment: This option is now obsolote, please use it with only single parameter pass  true if  it is used unicode characters  else pass false will be used WinAnsi encoding   PdfDocumentRenderer pdfRenderer = new PdfDocumentRenderer(true);